# Pretty <kbd> tags for U&L?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Stack Overflow and most (all?) other sites got a pretty <kbd>kbd</kbd> style [not so long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126998/kbd-elements-are-still-intrusive).

Will this eventually be propagated to Unix & Linux, or are we sticking with the old one on purpose?

Sample hypothetical before/after renderings (Chromium 19):

---

[image: old]
[image: pretty]

---

In a text block before:

> [image: old2]

After:

> [image: pretty2]

---

**Can we get the fancy `<kbd>`, pretty please?**

I mean, this doesn't really look good, does it?

> [image]

Comment: Any news on this front?  The biggest problem with the old `kbd` styling that we currently still have is that they are too large and don't fit in well with surrounding text.  Dense usage typical of posts about keyboard shortcuts (which is what `kbd` tags are for right?) ends up looking like a cramped mess.  Semantically `kbd` tags make more sense but I am sorely tempted to just ignore them and use normal `code` markup instead, in the interest of readability.

Comment: This is [getting ridiculous](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52673/use-m-c-m-v-m-a-for-copy-paste-select-all)...

Comment: No promises, but our designer is looking into it.

Comment: @Jaydles: Thanks for the feedback! Expecting an answer in the usual 6-8 week timeframe :-)

Comment: @Shog9: yay! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The nicely styled <kbd>kbd</kbd> tags are present in the mobile interface; surely it would not be difficult to migrate the CSS across to the main site?

**Update**
[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49809/console-text-editor-with-gui-like-keyboard-shortcuts-ctrl-z-x-c-v) presents a compelling argument for the change...

[image: keyboard screenie]

Comment: This is because the mobile site has a common skin, whereas each site gets its own main skin--and SE forgot (or deliberately ignored to preserve the design) unix.

Comment: @Manishearth They _forgot_ us?! :)

Comment: :P Either that or they deliberately wanted the old look of the kbd on U&L. It _does_ look appropriate here, to me :)

Answer (score -7):

With as "nuts & bolts" as Unix & Linux is, I don't think that the <kbd>kbd</kbd> format being a little "jarring" is a "bad thing".

It does kind of make the keyboard commands "pop out" at the user, which is a good thing if you're trying to walk through a guide for how to do something, and the keyboard commands help you keep your place.

I think I like keeping the old format.