# Enhancements to CSS for <kbd> needed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, css

If two consecutive lines have a  tag, the CSS effect gets overlapped. Maybe the height of the rectangle for  can be reduced or the line height can be changed?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: kbd overlap]

Comment: Related: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/952/pretty-kbd-tags-for-ul - I guess fixing the current one a bit would be better than nothing.

Comment: For a niche community of technical people it is disappointing that this and the [request to change the poor font choice for zeros](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716/question-title-font-renders-0-number-zero-much-like-o-lower-case-letter) are ignored...

Comment: @jasonwryan At least here we aren't getting [gray text on a gray background](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+design+meta).

Comment: @Gilles reading science fiction makes you go blind, obviously...

Answer (score 6):

I tried to get them to fix this [years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60980/overlap-of-kbd-elements), but they're strangely opposed; the fix is "don't do that". I wish they would just [give us nice-looking kbd tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/952/pretty-kbd-tags-for-ul). I'll poke somebody at Stack Exchange to see if there's any chance of that happening. Since this is [status-declined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) on the main meta I'm going to mark it the same here

Comment: Wow the answers on that linked question make me so sad ... :'(